Creating a custom component in Blazor Server
I want to create a component that enables users to **autocomplete **from a list of plaintiffs, in addition to allowing them to **create **a new plaintiff if **no results **are found. I know that there are already auto-complete components that already exist in UI libraries but I want to write my own custom component.
@page "/plaintiff-autocomplete"
@using System.Collections.Generic

<div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" @bind-value="plaintiffInput" @bind-value:event="oninput" placeholder="Type plaintiff name..." />
    <div class="autocomplete-items">
        @if (suggestions.Count > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var suggestion in suggestions)
            {
                <div @onclick="(() => SelectSuggestion(suggestion))">@suggestion</div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <div @onclick="ShowModal">No Results</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" @onclick="CloseModal">&times;</span>
            <h2>Add Plaintiff</h2>
            <form @onsubmit="AddPlaintiff">
                <label for="plaintiffName">Plaintiff Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="plaintiffName" @bind-value="newPlaintiff" required />
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string plaintiffInput = "";
    private List<string> plaintiffs = new List<string> { "John Doe", "Jane Smith", "David Johnson", "Emily Brown" };
    private List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
    private bool showModal = false;
    private string newPlaintiff = "";

    private void SelectSuggestion(string suggestion)
    {
        plaintiffInput = suggestion;
        suggestions.Clear();
    }

    private void ShowModal()
    {
        showModal = true;
    }

    private void CloseModal()
    {
        showModal = false;
    }

    private void AddPlaintiff()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPlaintiff))
        {
            plaintiffs.Add(newPlaintiff);
            plaintiffInput = newPlaintiff;
            showModal = false;
            newPlaintiff = "";
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSuggestions()
    {
        suggestions = plaintiffs.Where(p => p.ToLower().Contains(plaintiffInput.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
}


I tried creating my own component, all the code is in the .razor file. I am not sure exactly why my binds do not work. While i type in things the application doesnt load any of the results up, it just says "no results". I previously had the code where the autocomplete/filtering WAS working but i modified it a bit and then it stopped.
Also, clicking on "no results" doesn't do anything. I thought that i hooked up the functionality correctly but i guess not
EDIT: The main thing is working, but not sure why my modal DOES NOT pop up when i press Add New Plaintiff button?

<div class="autocomplete">
    <input class="form-control" list="autocompleteitems" placeholder="Select from the list or add a new Plaintiff" />
    <datalist id="autocompleteitems">
        @foreach (var suggestion in plaintiffs)
        {
            <option value="@suggestion" />
        }
    </datalist>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowModal">Add New Plaintiff</button>
@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal show">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Add Plaintiff</h5>
                    <button class="btn-close" @onclick="CloseModal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form @onsubmit="AddPlaintiff">
                        <label for="plaintiffName">Plaintiff Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="plaintiffName" @bind-value="newPlaintiff" required />
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string plaintiffInput = "";
    private List<string> plaintiffs = new List<string> { "John Doe", "Jane Smith", "David Johnson", "Emily Brown" };
    private List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
    private bool showModal = false;
    private string newPlaintiff = "";

    private void SelectSuggestion(string suggestion)
    {
        plaintiffInput = suggestion;
        suggestions.Clear();
    }

    private void ShowModal()
    {
        showModal = true;
    }

    private void CloseModal()
    {
        showModal = false;
    }

    private void AddPlaintiff()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPlaintiff))
        {
            plaintiffs.Add(newPlaintiff);
            plaintiffInput = newPlaintiff;
            showModal = false;
            newPlaintiff = "";
        }
    }

    private Task OnAfter()
    {
        suggestions = plaintiffs.Where(p => p.ToLower().Contains(plaintiffInput.ToLower())).ToList();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


   @page "/plaintiff-autocomplete"
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Linq

<div class="autocomplete">
    <input type="text" @bind="plaintiffInput" @oninput="UpdateSuggestions" placeholder="Type plaintiff name..." />
    <div class="autocomplete-items">
        @if (suggestions.Count > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var suggestion in suggestions)
            {
                <div @onclick="() => SelectSuggestion(suggestion)">@suggestion</div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <div>No Results</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" @onclick="CloseModal">&times;</span>
            <h2>Add Plaintiff</h2>
            <form @onsubmit="AddPlaintiff">
                <label for="plaintiffName">Plaintiff Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="plaintiffName" @bind="newPlaintiff" required />
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string plaintiffInput = "";
    private List<string> plaintiffs = new List<string> { "John Doe", "Jane Smith", "David Johnson", "Emily Brown" };
    private List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
    private bool showModal = false;
    private string newPlaintiff = "";

    private void SelectSuggestion(string suggestion)
    {
        plaintiffInput = suggestion;
        suggestions.Clear();
    }

    private void ShowModal()
    {
        showModal = true;
    }

    private void CloseModal()
    {
        showModal = false;
    }

    private void AddPlaintiff()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPlaintiff))
        {
            plaintiffs.Add(newPlaintiff);
            plaintiffInput = newPlaintiff;
            showModal = false;
            newPlaintiff = "";
            UpdateSuggestions();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateSuggestions()
    {
        suggestions = plaintiffs.Where(p => p.ToLower().Contains(plaintiffInput.ToLower())).ToList();
    }
}

Binding Issue: The binding might not be working properly due to missing invocation of the UpdateSuggestions() method. This method is responsible for updating the suggestions based on the user input. Currently, it's not being called anywhere in your component.
Event Handling: The event handler for showing the modal when there are no results is not properly set up. The ShowModal() method should not be directly used as an event handler. Instead, you should use an anonymous function to call it.

Did not compile

Sorry for that I will edit the code I hope that's help you
Thanks

Here's a version of your code that does the binding and updates the list.

Uses bind, not bind-Value which is incorrect for a input.
Uses the bind:after event to update the list.
Some formatting of the Modal using Bootstrap.

This may work, but it doesn't address various UI/UX issues with you design.
I've also added an auto-complete input using a data list to show a simpler alternative approach.
@using System.Collections.Generic

<div class="autocomplete m-3">
    <input type="text" @bind="plaintiffInput" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="OnAfter" placeholder="Type plaintiff name..." />
    <div id="autocomplete-items">
        @if (suggestions.Count > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var suggestion in suggestions)
            {
                <div @onclick="(() => SelectSuggestion(suggestion))">@suggestion</div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <div>No Results</div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowModal">Add New Plaintiff</button>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<div class="autocomplete">
    <input class="form-control" list="autocompleteitems" placeholder="Select from the list or add a new Plaintiff" />
    <datalist id="autocompleteitems">
        @foreach (var suggestion in plaintiffs)
        {
            <option value="@suggestion" />
        }
    </datalist>
</div>

@if (showModal)
{
    <div class="modal show" style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Add Plaintiff</h5>
                    <button class="btn-close" @onclick="CloseModal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form @onsubmit="AddPlaintiff">
                        <label for="plaintiffName">Plaintiff Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="plaintiffName" @bind-value="newPlaintiff" required />
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@code {
    private string plaintiffInput = "";
    private List<string> plaintiffs = new List<string> { "John Doe", "Jane Smith", "David Johnson", "Emily Brown" };
    private List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
    private bool showModal = false;
    private string newPlaintiff = "";

    private void SelectSuggestion(string suggestion)
    {
        plaintiffInput = suggestion;
        suggestions.Clear();
    }

    private void ShowModal()
    {
        showModal = true;
    }

    private void CloseModal()
    {
        showModal = false;
    }

    private void AddPlaintiff()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newPlaintiff))
        {
            plaintiffs.Add(newPlaintiff);
            plaintiffInput = newPlaintiff;
            showModal = false;
            newPlaintiff = "";
        }
    }

    private Task OnAfter()
    {
        suggestions = plaintiffs.Where(p => p.ToLower().Contains(plaintiffInput.ToLower())).ToList();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

